# Upgrading R from 4.2.0 to 4.2.1 on 18.04.6 LTS via recommended PPA states that 4.2.0 is latest

Tags: 18.04, r

I am trying to update R from 4.2.0 to 4.2.1 ([r-project.org](https://ftp.belnet.be/mirror/CRAN/)) according to the recommendations for installing on ubuntu. I have already added the ppa in the past, and used it to install `r-base-dev` on the system (Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS). However, after executing the instructions on r-project.org to install R for linux, there is no availability of `r-base` or `r-base-dev` 4.2.1 for Ubuntu 18 (bionic): `r-base-dev is already the newest version (4.2.0-1.1804.0)`, although it is an LTS release that should still be supported (at least as of May 2022 according to r-project.org). I don't know if this is the appropriate place to ask for help but I don't know where else to turn. When I check the URL https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/bionic-cran40/ it is also clear that all other releases are there except for 4.2.1. However, at https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/focal-cran40/ (for Ubuntu 20.04) the 4.2.1 is available. Google did not help me in finding a reason for the lack of availability for 18.04. I would prefer not to compile R from source on 18.04. Any insights/help are warmly welcome.

Code used:

```r
# update indices
sudo apt update -qq
# install two helper packages we need
sudo apt install --no-install-recommends software-properties-common dirmngr
# add the signing key (by Michael Rutter) for these repos
# To verify key, run gpg --show-keys /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/cran_ubuntu_key.asc 
# Fingerprint: E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
wget -qO- https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/marutter_pubkey.asc | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/cran_ubuntu_key.asc
# add the R 4.0 repo from CRAN -- adjust 'focal' to 'groovy' or 'bionic' as needed
sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs)-cran40/"
sudo apt install --no-install-recommends r-base
```

Comment: contact the maintainers and ask about why 4.2.1 is not available on bionic. They do say the latest version will be available for *most* stable desktop releases, but that only the latest LTS version is supported. They would know why bionic isn't supported, or if it was a mistake, they can fix it.